# data created from mongoose not showing on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a question related to mongodb..
currently, I am building rest api using node.js and express.js for android app. For database, I am using mongodb and mongoose... The problem I am having is that I can insert and print data using mongoose but it seems like the data inserted using mongoose not showing on mongodb..

What I tried is that I ran mongod and the server.js on the command line and inserted data using mongoose. And then, on the command line, I opened mongo --> use <dbname> --> db.<dbname>.find() shows nothing.. What did I do wrong?? Running mongod and the server.js on localhost

-- edit

```
passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy(
    {
        usernameField : 'email', // the name of username that got passed into this strategy
        passwordField : 'password', // the name of the password that got passed into tis strategy
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        // done(...) where ... is (err, user, info)
        process.nextTick(function() {
            // find user with username
            User.findOne({ email : email }, function(err, user){
                if(err) return done(err);
                if(user) return done(null, false, { message : 'User already exists.' });

                // save the user
                var newUser = new User();
                newUser.email = email;
                newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if(err) return done(err);
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            });
        });
    }
));
```

I am using passport for authentication and here I am inserting new user. I tried to print out all users by doing

```
User.find({}, function(err, users){
                console.log(users);
            });
```

just try to see that the new user is inserted.. and I see that all users from the log... however, if I go to command line mongo and do db.User.find(), I don't see anything..
Thanks!

Comment: can you post the code where you insert the data?

Comment: @eblahm editted.. ^^

Comment: did you try lowercase user `db.users.find()` or `db.user.find()` depending on what your collection is named

Comment: consider downloading this... http://robomongo.org/ ... its a good tool for querying and visualizing what in a mongo database without having to muck with command line arguements

Comment: @eblahm show dbs shows User. db.users.find() and db.user.find() did not work for me

Comment: @eChung00 what does `show collections` display in mongo? does it show the right collection?

Comment: @jackblank it worked!! lol what I did is "use User" --> "db.user.find()" and it shows correct data... One thing I do not understand is that I made a model with schema named "User" in mongoose and added data to it. Why is it not showing the data when I do "db.User.find()"??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how most people create a collection with mongoose

```
var User = mongoose.model("User",userSchema );
```

this will create a collection in mongoose called `users`. It will make the first letter a lowercase ie: "u" and add an "s". so you can check your data `db.users.find()` I hope this helps. I don't know if you know this information.

It also says something [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) about Compiling your first model.

> The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your model name.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026724/mongoose-collection-naming-bug) might also help

Comment: Thanks.. I am new to mongodb and node.js so I do not know much... your answer helped me a lot!!